# Prove that $kn+r$ isn't divisible by $k$ if $r$ isn't divisible by $k$ and $k$,$n$ and $r$ are integers.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I understand that this is trivial, but I never understood why, nor did I see a proof for it.

Comment: If $kn+r=ka$, then $r=k(a-n)$.

Comment: Well, if $kn$ is divisible by $k$ and $kn + r$ is divisible by $k$, then $kn + r - kn$ is.....

Answer (score 0):

Prove the contrapositive. If $k\mid r$, then $r=kj$ for some integer $j$ whence
$$
kn+r=k(n+j)
$$
as desired.

Answer (score 0):

1. Suppose $k$, $n$, and $r$ are integers and set $A = kn+r$.
2. If $r$ is an integer multiple of $k$ (say,  $r = ka$) then we can factor: $$A = kn+ r = kn +ka = k(n+a),$$
   which means that $A$ is a multiple of $k$.
3. Therefore, if $r$ is a multiple of $k$ then $A$ is.
4. The contrapositive of this statement is that if $A$ is not a multiple of $k$, then $r$ isn't either.
5. That's what we wanted to show, so we're done.